# Trying to execute a simple query, getting Syntax error: code 1 error at where clause.

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to update the contents of one row of DB here is my query:

```
public void updateAdhoc(String value1, String value2, String value3,String CONTACT_ID){

        int id = Integer.valueOf(CONTACT_ID);
        String update = "UPDATE Adhoc SET Name = " + "'"+value1+"'" +","+
                "DOB =  " + "'"+value2+"'" +","+
                "ImageData =  " + "'"+value3+"'" +","+
                "where " +adhocIdPrimary +"= " +id+";"; 

        mDb.execSQL(update);
    }
```

The code fails at the where clause. Following is my table creation string:

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE3 = "create table Adhoc (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
            +"DOB text, " +
            "Name text not null, " +
            "ImageData text);";
    static final String DATABASE_TABLE3 = "Adhoc";
```

And following are my variables referencing the column names:

```
//Table Adhoc 
public static final String adhocIdPrimary = "_id";
public static final String adhocName = "Name";
public static final String adhocDob = "DOB";
public static final String adhocImageData = "ImageData";
```

The LogCat:

```
02-03 10:57:50.017: E/AndroidRuntime(9576): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-03 10:57:50.017: E/AndroidRuntime(9576): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "where": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE Adhoc SET Name = 'Ram Lal',DOB =  '2014-2-3 ',ImageData =  '/data/data/com.ex.xxx/files/xxx/adhoc1391405269898.jpg',where _id= 1;
02-03 10:57:50.017: E/AndroidRuntime(9576):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
02-03 10:57:50.017: E/AndroidRuntime(9576):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
02-03 10:57:50.017: E/AndroidRuntime(9576):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
02-03 10:57:50.017: E/AndroidRuntime(9576):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
02-03 10:57:50.017: E/AndroidRuntime(9576):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
02-03 10:57:50.017: E/AndroidRuntime(9576):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
02-03 10:57:50.017: E/AndroidRuntime(9576):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1663)
02-03 10:57:50.017: E/AndroidRuntime(9576):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1594)
02-03 10:57:50.017: E/AndroidRuntime(9576):     at com.exa.birthdayrem.DBAdapter.updateAdhoc(DBAdapter.java:421)
02-03 10:57:50.017: E/AndroidRuntime(9576):     at com.ex.xxx.AdhocEdit$3.onClick(AdhocEdit.java:207)
02-03 10:57:50.017: E/AndroidRuntime(9576):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4091)
02-03 10:57:50.017: E/AndroidRuntime(9576):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17072)
02-03 10:57:50.017: E/AndroidRuntime(9576):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
02-03 10:57:50.017: E/AndroidRuntime(9576):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-03 10:57:50.017: E/AndroidRuntime(9576):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
02-03 10:57:50.017: E/AndroidRuntime(9576):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5000)
02-03 10:57:50.017: E/AndroidRuntime(9576):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-03 10:57:50.017: E/AndroidRuntime(9576):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-03 10:57:50.017: E/AndroidRuntime(9576):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
02-03 10:57:50.017: E/AndroidRuntime(9576):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
02-03 10:57:50.017: E/AndroidRuntime(9576):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `,` before `WHERE` and provide space after `adhocIdPrimary`

It will look like

```
String update = "UPDATE Adhoc SET Name = " + "'"+value1+"'" +","+
            "DOB =  " + "'"+value2+"'" +","+
            "ImageData =  " + "'"+value3+"'" +" "+
            "where " +adhocIdPrimary +" = " +id+";"; `
```

Answer (score 5):

You have an unwanted `,` comma before the `where` word. Just remove it and run again.

```
String update = "UPDATE Adhoc SET Name = " + "'"+value1+"'" +","+
                "DOB =  " + "'"+value2+"'" +","+
                "ImageData =  " + "'"+value3+"'" +","+   // remove this last comma
                "where " +adhocIdPrimary +"= " +id+";";
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove comma that is before `where` and replace it with space:

```
String update = "UPDATE Adhoc SET Name = " + "'"+value1+"'" +","+
            "DOB =  " + "'"+value2+"'" +","+
            "ImageData =  " + "'"+value3+"'" +" "+
            "where " +adhocIdPrimary +"= " +id+";";
```